# Code to add items to a data grid is not working. Not sure whats wrong. I want to add all the columns into the gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable, datarow

My Public Class is Below:

```
public class GlobalVariable
        public shared listbox2Count = listbox2.items.count
        public shared containsListbox2Item
End Class
```

my code where i assign a text item to a variable object:

```
Public Function getListBoxText()

    If ListBox2.Text = "X,Y Coordinate" Then
        GlobalVariable.containsListBox2Item = "X,Y Coordinate"
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "Latitude, Longitude" Then
        GlobalVariable.containsListBox2Item = "Latitude, Longitude"

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

My code where i am stuck is below:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To GlobalVariable.listbox2Count - 1
            If GlobalVariable.containsListBox2Item(i) = "X,Y Coordinate" Then
                dt.Columns.Add("X Coordinate")
                dt.Columns.Add("Y Coordinate")
            ElseIf GlobalVariable.containsListBox2Item(i) = "Latitude, Longitude" Then
                If (Not dt.Columns.Contains("Latitude")) Then dt.Columns.Add("Latitude")
                If (Not dt.Columns.Contains("Longitude")) Then dt.Columns.Add("Longitude")
            End If
        Next
        Dim mr As DataRow
        mr = dt.NewRow
                mr("X Coordinate") = "203910"
                mr("Y Coordinate") = "190280"
                mr("Latitude") = "100022"
                mr("Longitude") = "201999"
        dt.Rows.Add(mr)
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

I am absolutely not sure whats wrong with this code and if someone can help me or correct it for me would be great help Thanks. I want to add all four columns into the grid view. and then keep adding more and more columns using else if.

Comment: on your first question about this, I proposed a solution that worked as you wanted, did you even try it??

Comment: hey i did try it. but i just want to show all four columns. however, i am only either getting x,y coordinate being read or latitude, longitude to appear on the grid view. 
is there a problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, its extensive but it does work, it displays all the values you have on listbox2

```
  Dim i As Integer
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim Card As String = ""
    Dim Geo As String = ""

    For i = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox2.Items.Item(i).Text = "X,Y Coordinate" Then
            If Card = "ok" Then

            Else
                dt.Columns.Add("X Coordinate")
                dt.Columns.Add("Y Coordinate")
                Card = "ok"
            End If
        ElseIf ListBox2.Items.Item(i).Text = "Latitude, Longitude" Then
            If Geo = "ok" Then

            Else
                dt.Columns.Add("Latitude")
                dt.Columns.Add("Longitude")
                Geo = "ok"
            End If
        End If
    Next


    Dim mr As DataRow

    For i = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox2.Items.Item(i).Text.Contains(dt.Columns.Item(0).ToString.Substring(0, 1)) Then
            If dt.Columns.Item(0).ToString = "Latitude" Then
                mr = dt.NewRow
                mr("Latitude") = "100909"
                mr("Longitude") = "1002929"


            ElseIf dt.Columns.Item(0).ToString = "X Coordinate" Then
                mr = dt.NewRow
                mr("X Coordinate") = "909090"
                mr("Y Coordinate") = "109209"
            End If

        End If

        If ListBox2.Items.Item(i).Text.Contains(dt.Columns.Item(2).ToString.Substring(0, 1)) Then
            If dt.Columns.Item(2).ToString = "Latitude" Then
                mr("Latitude") = "100909"
                mr("Longitude") = "1002929"

            ElseIf dt.Columns.Item(2).ToString = "X Coordinate" Then
                mr("X Coordinate") = "909090"
                mr("Y Coordinate") = "109209"
            End If
        End If

        Dim res As Integer
        res = i Mod 2

        If res > 0 Or i = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 Then

            dt.Rows.Add(mr)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: hey i am pretty sure i dont need to do all this just to get all columns to show up right? i am adding columns which i need all four columns to show up. do i need to do all this?

Comment: tried it and getting errors during start time. i am not sure if i am explaining my issue properly. if you want we can take this to a chat?

Comment: well since you want to add the columns of the `datatable` dynamically, yes, if you leave the `datatable` "fixed", to display the 4 columns, even if the user only has selected one item, its easier to do

Comment: but the thing is it wont always only have 4 columns. it can have multiple multiple or maybe just one column. the column count is not determined. if i items x,y and lat,lon exist in listbox 2 all i want to do is add the columns in the gridview, and under neath each column have the assigned row values.

Comment: thats why you need that much code, you first check how many items there are on listbox2, and what type of items (x,y or lat,long) and depending on those you add the columns to the datatable, then you check again those items to add the right value to each one (x=909090, y=109209 and so)

Comment: Hey this worked. Thank you sir!. can you please give my question an upvote i will mark this as an answer!. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple Form that defines a GridView by using the contents of a ListBox to provide Column Information

**Important** I've altered the ListBox Values to represent Column Headers.  See why below.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Text="X,Y Coordinate" Value="X Coordinate, Y Coordinate" />
      <asp:ListItem Text="Latitude, Longitude" Value="Latitude, Longitude" />
    </asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
      EmptyDataText="No Data" ShowHeader="true">
    </asp:GridView>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### Code Behind

```
Public Class WebForm1
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  ' DataTable Name and Application Cache Key
  Const DataTableCacheKey As String = "CoordinatesDataTable"

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Create the Table and add to Cache, only once
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        CreateDataTableFromListView()
    End If

    GridView1.DataSource = Cache(DataTableCacheKey)
    GridView1.DataBind()
  End Sub
```

---

**Create the DataSource**
NOTE:  By using the Value Property of the ListItem as a comma separated list of strings, you can associate multiple columns to a given Coordinate system.  Note this is not the ideal way because there is no way set up a data type, I'm assuming everything is a Double value.  Still it's far better than a long string of `If` conditions to determine columns and headers.

```
  ' All the magic happens here...
  Private Sub CreateDataTableFromListView()

    ' Instantiate a DataTable with a table name
    Dim dt As New DataTable(DataTableCacheKey)

    ' Loop throught the ListBox and...
    For Each li As ListItem In ListBox2.Items

        ' Split each Value Property into an array 
        ' of strings to use as Column identifiers
        Dim ColumnHeaders() As String = li.Value.Split(",")

        ' Loop through the array of strings to create
        ' DataTable Columns
        For Each ch As String In ColumnHeaders
            dt.Columns.Add(ch, GetType(Double))
        Next
    Next

    ' Add an initial Blank Row 
    Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

    ' Loop Through Columns and set a default 
    ' value of 0 for each column 
    For Each c As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        row(c.ColumnName) = 0
    Next

    ' Add the Row to the Table
    dt.Rows.Add(row)

    ' Persist the DataTable to the Application cache
    Cache(DataTableCacheKey) = dt

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: all i am trying to do is take a count of all the items in the listbox, and then add them as columns in the data table and display rows underneath them in a grid view. I just dont know how to code it.

Comment: if i items x,y and lat,lon exist in listbox 2 all i want to do is add the columns in the gridview, and under neath each column have the assigned row values

Comment: Modified my answer.  Hope this helps.